# xgboost4j-spark missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'XGBoost.class'

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost

I use xgboost with spark

scala version:2.11.8

java version:1.7

spark version:2.1.0

maven dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ml.dmlc/xgboost4j-spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ml.dmlc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xgboost4j-spark</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

i use idea ,when i write codes,there is no error,but when i want to package my project to jar ,it shows that error.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is lacking xgboost4j dependency,just add in maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ml.dmlc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xgboost4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
</dependency>
```